# Назначение и синтаксис тега meta

Tags: веб-программирование, теги, php, html, книги

В книге Лауры Томсон "Разработка Web-приложений на PHP и MySQL" написано в главе про объектно-ориентированное программирование следующее:

- 

> Большинство коммерческих Web-страниц включают в себя метадескрипторы, помогающие поисковым механизмам выполнять их индексацию. Чтобы они были полезны, метадескрипторы, вероятно, должны изменяться от страницы к странице. В этом
> случае мы также определяем значение по умолчанию (эта есть атрибут класса Page):

```
    var $keywords = "TLA Consulting, Three Letter Abbreviation,
    some of my best friends are search engines";
```

- Затем несколько спустя приводится код, в котором используется эта переменная
  вместе с метатегом:

  ```
  function DisplayKeywords
  {
     echo "<META name=\"keywords\" content=\"$this->keywords\">"
  }
  ```

Прочитав страницу [Мета-теги](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8), я заметил различие в синтаксисе тега `META`, а именно в использовании слэшей при задании значений свойств `name` и `content`. Поясните назначение тега `META` **в данном случае (что выводит оператор echo)** (стр. 149-156), **что выводится и различие в синтаксисе**.

Answer (score 2):

Эти **бэк**слэши - экранирование двойных кавычек в других двойных кавычках в php,  в выводе их нет.

В данном случае тег META сообщает поисковому роботу наиболее важные,  с точки зрения менеджера вебсайта **ключевые слова**

`echo` используется чтобы **вывести** строку содержащую переменное значение. можно и "без него", например (должны быть включены short tags):

```
function DisplayKeywords
{ 
?>
<META name="keywords" content="<?=$this->keywords"?>>
<?php
}
```

Comment: В дополнение к ответу порекомендую почитать о базовых понятиях вроде строк, чисел, булевых и.т.п. не в книге, а в официальной документации. Благо там все хорошо описано:  
http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php

Comment: @eicto и @ReinRaus не могли бы вы объяснить назначение тега `META` **в данном случае**?

Comment: @ReinRaus я тоже хотел сказать о доке, но решил сначала качнуть книгу и посмотреть можно ли ей вообще доверять.

Comment: @ivan89 в плане работы с mysql доверять **нельзя**, в книге описан устаревший даже на момент публикации способ связи с базой данных используя расширение php-mysql. 

в остальные места сильно не вчитывался, но исходя из вышеозначенного, я думаю там описанны паттерны работы как минимум 6ти летней давности, что делает книгу почти полностью бесполезной, т.к. когда вы освоите их полностью они станут 10-11 летними, и вы окажетесь в роли устаревшего вебпрограмиста.

Comment: [depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: @eicto я из комментария

> Большинство коммерческих Web-страниц включают в себя метадескрипторы, помогающие поисковым механизмам выполнять их индексацию. Чтобы они были полезны, метадескрипторы, вероятно, должны изменяться от страницы к странице. В этом случае мы также определяем значение по умолчанию (эта есть атрибут класса Page):

примерно понял, что делает оператор `META`, но не понял зачем в функции `DisplayKeywords` нужен оператор `echo` (не могли бы глянуть страницы 149-156 этой книги хотя бы мельком, со своей стороны скажу, что там создается в одном файле класс страницы Page,

Comment: @eicto и @ReinRaus и этот класс используется для создании страницы. Также оцените тем самым информацию по ООП в этой книге.

Comment: @eicto и @ReinRaus я понял, что `META` служит для индексации по ключевым словам, но зачем в таком случае для html тега используется оператор echo?

Comment: потому-что для разных страниц могут быть разные ключевые слова. поэтому мы делаем метод DisplayKeywords и вносим его в класс генератора страницы. Например наследуемый класс может изменить эту переменную. 


книжку мне читать неохота, вряд-ли  там что-то интересное для меня будет. вообще в книжках по программированию, особенно по конкретным языкам обычно мало толку. Все нетленки уже написаны еще до 90х, а по современному состоянию - Документация, практика, IRC, форумы.